# jquery ie errors?! animate?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-animate

ie being quite baffling at the mo!

really domn't know how;

```
$("#info").delay(500).animate({ 
        'left': "0px",
}, 250 );
```

can throw an erro but it does? Thinks its the animate but not sure how?

link http://rundell.modernactivity.co.uk/
(line 175-177)
works fine in all other browsers.

any help welcome...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is because of the trailing comma

try

```
$("#info").delay(500).animate({ 
        'left': "0px"
}, 250 );
```

notice how the comma after "0px" is removed? this will fix your error. in the future, remove all trailing commas from hashes because it will blow up IE in most epic ways.